# QGIS 2.2 Print Composer does not display map with some datasets

Tags: qgis

I can't seem to get the Print Composer of QGIS 2.2 to work. When I click on "Add new map", the map square is created, but I can't seem to see my data in it, whatever the scale I use or even clicking on "set to map canvas extent". When I add a Legend, the contents are correct, all the layers I have rendered on the main QGIS window are listed there.

Can anyone help me with this, please? Thanks!

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. Everything works fine for me. What system you are working with? What about your data?

Comment: I'm working on Win 7. I've been running tests and from what I can gather, this seems to be the only dataset with that problem, although I can't understand why - I've created it exactly in the same way as I have created others that don't seem to cause this problem.

Comment: Here's a sample from that dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfxsaig9msxpbxs/Limite_GRO.rar

I have some more shapefiles and also some generated raster from these shapefiles. None of them is being rendered in the Print Composer.

Comment: Apparently, the problem is with the CRS. I had prepared all the data with a local CRS (EPSG 27493). After reprojecting to WGS 84 (EPSG 4326) the Print Composer started rendering all correctly. In this case, it's fine since for the purpose of this work it's not important. But if QGIS Print Composer is having problems dealing with some CRS, this can be an issue in the future for me and other users...

Comment: Yes, probably the issue is the CRS. Perhaps you could try to ask clarifications to qgis-dev mailing list

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm issues with the sample data in QGIS 2.2 Print Composer but it works fine with the current test version which will be 2.4 in a few weeks.